# Get only the first paragraph out of description tag of rss feed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

How do I get only the first paragraph out of the description tag of rss feed with jquery?
i'm using the zepto.js .

here the xml code
     `<description>
     <p>Insiders vertellen tegen <a href="http://www.tmz.com/2013/11/18/justin-bieber-chris-brown-ti-floyd-mayweather-party-naked-girls-strippers-disturbing-the-peace-police/" target="_blank">TMZ</a> dat Floyd Mayweather, Chris Brown, T.I., Trey Songz en Snoop Lion hun ogen uitkeken. Behalve de strippers waren er ook genoeg andere schaarsgeklede vrouwen op het feest.</p> <p>Bieber strooide naar verluidt de hele avond met dollars om de dames te behagen. In totaal smeet hij omgerekend ruim 7300 euro over de balk. Een van de strippers zou bijna 1000 euro hebben verdiend.</p> <p><strong>Drank en wiet</strong></p> <p>De beroemde gasten van de 19-jarige popzanger hoefden het niet zonder verdovende middelen te stellen. Er was volgens de ingewijden genoeg drank en wiet op voorraad voor iedereen.</p> <p>De buren waren trouwens een stuk minder blij met het feestje van Bieber. Ze belden tot drie keer toe de politie, onder meer omdat de muziek veel te hard stond.</p>
</description>`

This is everything i got:

```
var element = $(xml).find("item").first();  
$("#content .align").html($(element).find("description").text());
```

Comment: `p:first` or `.get(0)` what you're after, per chance?

Answer (score 0):

Find first paragraph by using

```
var element=$(xml).find("description p:first").text()
```

And then add this text by using

```
$("#content").text(element);
```

You can also append html to this element